# Mac OS X Symlink on home dir

Tags: mac

I use Linux as my primary desktop, my path is on this workstation is `/home/matt`, I have a good few places and configs that I sync between Linux and my Mac via Dropbox, on my mac my home path is `/Users/matt`. e.g. local bookmarks are sync via Firefox Weave (like XMarks) such as `file://home/matt/My Dropbox/offlinepages/jquery-help.html`

I'm trying to symlink `/home/matt` to `/Users/Matt` on my mac so everything aligns equally, but I get `Operation not permitted` even under a `sudo bash`.

Comment: My reading of your question is that your Mac is a different machine to your Linux box. Is this right?

Comment: It actually says: *Operation not supported*. I was unable to do it [this way](http://www.dwright.us/?p=581) without reboot, but it might work for you.

Comment: @Lukasa. Wouldnt really be a question would it? Should the last character of your username be 's' not 'a'? I think so. Thanks Daniel for the link. sudo ln -s /Users/Matt /home/matt worked perfect after removing that line from auto_master.

Comment: You never know. Imagine how silly I'd look if I assumed you meant a local machine and not a remote one, or vice versa. And no, it's just Lukasa. It's totally unrelated to my RL name.

Answer (score 4):

You need to disable automount.  Use `sudo edit /etc/auto_master` to comment out the `/home` line.  My auto_master file looks like:

```
#
# Automounter master map
#

+auto_master            # Use directory service
/net                    -hosts          -nobrowse,hidefromfinder,nosuid
# /home                 auto_home       -nobrowse,hidefromfinder
/Network/Servers        -fstab
/-                      -static
```

Then run `sudo automount -v -c`.

You should see the output:

```
automount: /net updated
automount: /home unmounted
```